# Приведение типов с помощью #

Tags: f#

В чём отличие между:

```
let f (inp : seq<'a>) = ..
```

и

```
let f (inp : #seq<'a>) = ..
```

Comment: Хороший вопрос, во втором случае это так называемый гибкий тип. В документации об этом есть [Flexible Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/flexible-types)

Comment: Если напишите самостоятельно ответ будет идеально =)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы лучше понять разницу, рекомендую использовать сервис sharplab.io
Итак, для первого варианта вы получаете функцию, которая на вход принимает IEnumerable

```
f (inp : seq<'a>) = ...// F#
f<a>(IEnumerable<a> inp) {...}// C#
```

Для второго варианта вы получаете функцию с двумя generic параметрами

```
f (inp : #seq<'t>) = ...// F#
f<a, t>(a f) where a : IEnumerable<t> ...// C#
```

Более подробно можно посмотреть [здесь](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfABK5wCmAXZYCMyAFAJYB2ADsiMhBgI4A8A5AIYB8AlMgLwCwAUGiFEOAoZhxgATETKVqAYlqMmWTjzHDUhDkA===)